# cannot load the dashboard to kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk, metricbeat

I tried various ways to fix this issue without any success.

Step - edit the metricbeat YAML and edit the kibana host

```
Index setup finished.
    Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
    Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://kibmonitor-kb-http.default.svc.clu
    ster.local:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET request: Get "http://kibmonitor-kb-http.default.svc.cluster.local:5
    601/api/status": EOF. Response: .
```

Appreciate your support for resolve this issue.